# ZSH completion removes the argument with compadd -U

Tags: zsh, completion

I'm trying to add a completion to a custom `vs` function which basically open the first filename matching the argument.

OPTIONAL (If you want more information about this function you can find my medium post here => https://medium.com/@victor.boissiere/how-to-quickly-open-files-with-your-editor-1a51b3fe21bf)

In my current folder I have the following:

- `./example.sh`
- `./custom/directory.sh`
- `./custom/example.sh`

## Behavior

`vs direct<TAB>` => completes to `custom/directory.sh` SUCCESS

`vs example<TAB>` => `vs`

Why does it **removes the argument** and does not let me choose between `example.sh` and `custom/example.sh` ?

## Code

```
_vs() {
  local curcontext="$curcontext" state line expl

  _arguments -C \
    '*:: :->open_files'

  case "$state" in
    open_files)
      local file=${words[CURRENT]}
      compadd -U - `find . -type f -ipath "*$file*" | sed "s|^\./||"`
      ;;
  esac
  return 0
}

compdef _vs vs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution thanks to this post => https://superuser.com/questions/1264778/changing-to-a-directory-found-somewhere-in-the-tree-hierarchy/1278919#1278919

I just needed to add `compstate[insert]=menu # no expand`

## Solution

```
_vs() {
  local curcontext="$curcontext" state line expl

  _arguments -C \
    '*:: :->open_files'

  case "$state" in
    open_files)
      local file=${words[CURRENT]}
      compadd -U - `find . -type f -ipath "*$file*" | sed "s|^\./||"`
      compstate[insert]=menu # add this
      ;;
  esac
  return 0
}

compdef _vs vs
```